# Image clustering with extracted feature vectors on a large dataset

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, numpy-ndarray, tensorflow-datasets

I've been trying to use a number of clustering techniques on an extremely large image dataset (around 1 million images). The process is quite standard - e.g., using a pretrained CNN (VGG19 in this case) to extract features and testing a number of clustering approaches (hierarchical and k-means at the moment) to group the images together. This works on a subset of my data.

However, when I do this on my large dataset, I have two main problems:

- The majority of clustering examples in Python require an array as the input. My data is too large to fit into an array in memory (I have 64gb at the moment).
- I can process the features in VGG16 using the image generators/batch methods in keras, but then I cannot find a way to use these outputs in clustering algorithms (e.g., scipy's hierarchical clustering or sklearn clustering) without converting to an array.

I essentially can't seem to figure out how to move those extracted features (which can easily be processed in batches) to a clustering method without using an array.

The images actually come from around 4,000 'classes' but they are not entirely different across classes. The goal of this clustering method is to reduce those classes to much broader categories using unsupervised clustering - so I do need all the data, and I have no way to subset it (I have already used a test case from a random sample of images, now I'm trying to apply it to the whole dataset).

Is there a way to get around using arrays for clustering packages like in scipy or sklearn, or should I be approaching this in a different way?

I've tried looking at TensorFlow datasets, using dask and numpy mmemap, but I can't quite figure out how to take any of those objects/examples and process them using a clustering algorithm. In essence I've had some luck processing and storing the extracted feature as an output, but seem to be stuck at moving this into a clustering model/different model.

I have also explored dimensionality reduction, but again I can't find anything to work conveniently with something like TF datasets where my processed features can be stored easily from the model.

UPDATE: After some investigating and helpful comments, it seems the pairwise distance calculation is the problem which is required for some clustering algorithms. That still leaves me with a few I can use (Batch KMeans for example), although I'd be interested if there were other solutions to calculating pairwise distance over larger arrays/features.

Comment: What's the size of one feature vector? By the way, I think the best way to solve this problem is to run a map-reduce version of your clustering algorithm. Otherwise you can sample your dataset and conduct your analysis on a subset of your data

Comment: Is the array an object - feature array or rather an all vs all object-object array? If the latter, you could look into network clustering algorithms where generically a cut-off is used and similarities above the cutoff induce a (weighted) edge between two objects, leading to a data structure (network) that is much sparser and typically stored as  a sparse matrix. There is still the issue of all vs all comparison. In some applications an index can speed this up.

Comment: I've been waiting for a model to finish to calculate the feature vector size but sadly still running. Anyway, each image is (224,224,3) and VVG16 outputs 4092 features, so the size of the array is (n,4092). Even more confusing to me, I stored the extracted features on disk and its size is only 5gb, but I think the pairwise distance array from the features is the issue now. The array is a feature array, so not all vs all object-object array, however I might still investigate network clustering as a potential solution.

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you call "pairwise distance array from the features" is what I call "object-object" array; this will thus have size (n,n), correct? In that case your observation that this is/may-be the issue now makes sense, and network clustering algorithms may well be worth investigating.

Comment: This would explain a lot. I'll update my original post- the feature array itself isn't the problem, it's the pairwise distance array (object-object array) as you mentioned required for some of the clustering algorithms I'm trying to use. Thanks for recommending the network clustering algorithms - I'll definitely take a look!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the similarity or distance measure between two feature vectors?